# bumblebee vs nvidia-prime? What to use that works with latest nvidia driver?

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

Bumblebee would be better, because I want to use the Nvidia card with specific apps like Blender but not with Gimp. But right now I can't find anything that helps me to install driver+bumblebee from scratch with the latest driver.

Can Nvidia Prime do that? Use it only for specific apps? Which is better right now? I haven't used Linux for a while.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience bumblebee is a fine balance between performance and battery life. It has been reported, however, that installing nvidia-prime will cause better performance on gaming, for example.

Nvidia-prime cannot be activated in a per-app basis, so if that is what you need from it you should go with bemblebee.

You can arguably install the latest drivers with bumblebee provided you install specific ppa for that.